# Angular passes variable as undefined to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I'm building an app on top of MEANJS. Here is my view:

```
<section data-ng-controller="PostsController" data-ng-init="findOne()">
...
    <span data-ng-controller="FavsController" ng-init="isFaved(post._id)">
        <button type="button" ng-hide="faved[post._id]"></button>
    </span>
...
</section>
```

And here is my function located in `FavsController`:

```
$scope.isFaved = function(postId) {
    console.log(postId);
    // other stuff. create an array named faved etc.
};
```

Problem is, `post._id` passes as `undefined` to function. But when I put say `{{ post._id }}` in my view, it prints the current post id, no matter where in the html. When I provide post id by typing (I mean like `isFaved(123)`), it is working and the inner button's `ng-hide` is also working properly. I'm using same `html` and same `js` with some other views, but only this one throws an error. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: post._id exists on FavsController initiation? Can you provide the post initialization code?  If you can provide a Splnkr or Jsfiddle for the issue it might be easier to solve.

Comment: @OrGuz no it doesn't exists on FavsController initiation and this never been a problem. I'm not  sure how to set all this on JsFiddle.

Comment: It's possible you are trying to use the post._id before angular is done processing the value.

Comment: @marcieng you are saying it doesn't exist on FavsController initialization but you expect ng-init to call isFaved with an item which doesn't exist? I guess this is why it is undefined. Where do you create the post?

Comment: @codebob is probably right. ngInit executes only once, and ngHide updates at every digest. So the value is probably not set when ngInit is executed.

Comment: @CodeBob so how i can ensure that angular done processing the value?

Comment: @OrGuz post._id exists in parent scope already.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-init is great for pre-setting values, and is intended to be used for aliasing properties inside of an ng-repeat.
What you would really want is to either tie the function call to an appropriate event like...

```
ng-click="isFaved(post._id)"
```

Or initialize the values or variables in the controller so you can ensure that they will exist with a value.  The use of ng-init in this situation isn't really how it was intended so you can expect the unexpected.

Comment: glad you got it taken care of.